# WPF data binding with inner elements

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind my StackPanel component to an object and its properties to elements it the StackPanel

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="device1" Background="#CC119EDA" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <Label FontSize="22" Foreground="White">Desk #1</Label>                   
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind

```
device1.DataContext = new Class { Name = "Name" };
```

What is wrong with this binding? Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you remove `DataContext="{Binding}"` from your `<StackPanel>` XAML? There's no need to set the `DataContext` in both XMAL and code-behind, and its possible the XAML setter is running after the code-behind code. Also, maybe it's just me but I don't think `Object` has a `Name` property. Is that a custom class? And is the `Name` property public, and does it have `get;` and `set;` accessors? Both are needed to bind to the property.

Comment: Object is for example only

Comment: @user3916810 did u implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong with your binding - if I paste your code into a new WPF project it functions correctly.  My `Class` had just a single auto-implemented `Name` property and I set the `DataContext` after the `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this. When u set the property to the Object , the UI Thread is not aware of the change , so you need to Implement RaisePropertyChange Mechanism. Using MvvmLight Toolkit is great advantage . Here the window datacontext is set to so could inherit all elements.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string MyName
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyName");
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyName = "Eldho";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Label>Hi,</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyName}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```